# URI must be ascii only error with Bootstrap gem in RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have installed Bootstrap gem for Rails via bundle, changed file in */app/assets/stylesheets/application.css* to *.scss* extension, removed `*= require_self`, `*= require_tree` and added this:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@font-face{
font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
src: image-url("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
src: image-url("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?‪#‎iefix‬") format("embedded-opentype"),
image-url("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format("woff"),
image-url("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
image-url("bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format("svg")
}
```

But when I restarted web server this error came up:

```
URI must be ascii only "bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?\u{202a}#\u{200e}iefix\u{202c}"
```

along with this part of code:

```
<head>
  <title>App</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> # problematic line
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Comment: does changing `image-url` to `font-url` do anything?

Comment: trying removing the IE fix and retyping it? perhaps stray utf chars during cut and paste?

Comment: @Doon It works now, thanks!